# How can I resort a column with number in order to the sort of a column that is date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. I want to sort a column that is number in order of another column that is date and i want to save it too. I just don't want a form or report. I want to save it

For example I have a table that has following columns:

```
factorno     spdate            sc
-----------------------------------
    1        2019-10-06         1
    1        2019-10-07         2
    2        2019-10-08         2
```

I want to update the column of `factorno` like this:

```
factorno     spdate            sc
----------------------------------
    1        2019-10-06         1
    2        2019-10-07         2
    3        2019-10-08         2
```

Please help me

Comment: Can you add the table definition please.

Comment: You wouldn't generally store derived data

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an oversimplified question but you could use a variable to generate a new factorno

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(factorno  int, spdate  date, sc int);
insert into t values
(    1     ,   '2019-10-06'     ,    1),
(    1     ,   '2019-10-07'     ,    2),
(    2     ,   '2019-10-08'     ,    2);

update t join (select spdate,@rn := @rn + 1 rn from t cross join (select @rn:=0) r order by spdate) s
            on s.spdate = t.spdate
set factorno = s.rn 
where 1 = 1;

select * from t;

+----------+------------+------+
| factorno | spdate     | sc   |
+----------+------------+------+
|        1 | 2019-10-06 |    1 |
|        2 | 2019-10-07 |    2 |
|        3 | 2019-10-08 |    2 |
+----------+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you are on version 8 or above you could use the row_number function. BTW data stored in sql has no specific order you always have to use ORDER BY to get the data in order you want so I don't see that there is anything gained by rebuilding factorno.

Comment: hi
thanks for answering but i cant understand what s is.
pls explain it
thnx

Comment: Remove it and see what happens (every sub query must have an alias)